# Accessing text selected in SelectionArea Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am using `SelectionArea` on top of a `ListView` with Texts.

Is there a way to access the selected text in the [`SelectionArea`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectionArea-class.html) Class?

Looking for a callback method like [`onSelectionChanged`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText/onSelectionChanged.html) from the [`SelectableText`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html) Class.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SelectionArea(
        child: ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
            List.generate(index + 1, (index) => 'Lorem Ipsum').join(' '),
          ),
          separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const SizedBox(height: 20),
          itemCount: 50,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this issue is open on [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107073), there has to be a new feature to implement this functionality in the future. They labeled this issue as a valid feature request.